# Assigning weights to a portfolio in R

Tags: r

I am trying to show in R how I can assign weights to the portfolio and then calculate the daily return. Below is the data for daily return and I have assigned 25% weight to each of them for making an equal weight portfolio and to calculate the returns. (There are 4 company stocks out of which i have just provided data for 2 stocks, hence 25% weight to each stock has been given) However, I am unbale to configure the same in R.

```
Workings: 

25% = 636.99*25% = 159.25
      633.79*25% = 158.45

Returns = Closing - opening 
        = 159.25-158.45
        = -0.80

Is there any way I can show this in R?


    AMZN     25%    Returns  GOOG     25%   Returns
    636.99  159.25          741.84  185.46  
    633.79  158.45  -0.80   742.58  185.65   0.18
    632.65  158.16  -0.28   743.62  185.90   0.26
    607.94  151.99  -6.18   726.39  181.60  -4.31
    607.05  151.76  -0.22   714.47  178.62  -2.98
    617.74  154.43   2.67   716.03  179.01   0.39
    617.89  154.47   0.04   726.07  181.52   2.51
    581.81  145.45  -9.02   700.56  175.14  -6.38
```

Comment: Many ways to accomplish this, but I'd probably define weights `GOOG_w = .25`, `AMZN_w = .25` etc. You could also use a source spreadsheet tracking the weights. I wouldn't store the data in your provided format though. I'd go more along the lines of `Ticker Symbol | Share Price | Number of Shares | Value in Portfolio | Returns`

Comment: Also note that while your starting weights are equal at 25%, that is only true at the beginning. As soon as a share price changes your portfolio is no longer equally weighted, so your 25% columns are not really accurate in your example.

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: Another question though: why are you calculating "25%" based on the stock price? A) generally you can't own a fraction of a share, B) if you're building an equally weighted portfolio, you'd be building it based on your starting capital, not share price. I.E. I have $1,000, so if I were to create equally weighted portfolio of four stocks, I'd buy $250 of each stock in question.

Comment: Agreed to the logic. The 25% weight I have taken here for simplicity sake to understand the working. I am just trying to understand how the portfolio returns are calculated in R when we have equal weighted portfolio.

Comment: Returns are simply Current Price - Base Price. Percent Return is (Current Price - Base Price)/Base Price

Comment: I have applied the below to incorporate the 25% weight to the portfolio: apply(mydf[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x))*0.25. Does it look right?

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out already, multiplying share prices by weights and subtracting to compute returns is not the correct approach for computing portfolio returns.  To understand why, think of a portfolio which has two stocks with 50% weight each, where stock A is worth $100 per share and stock B is worth $1 per share.  If they both go up by 10%, your method will not say the portfolio went up by 10%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returns should be divided, not subtracted.  Your 1-day return for Amazon should be calculated as `633.79 / 636.69 - 1 = -0.0046`.  An equal-weighted portfolio could just take the mean of these four returns on day 2.

Beyond day 2, you need to think about how often your portfolio is rebalanced.  This is more a topic for quant.stackexchange.com, and not a programming question.  But I'll give you both the (unrealistic) case where you assume the portfolio is perfectly equal-weighted at the start of each day, and the (simple & realistic) case where we set the portfolio to be equal weighted at the start and we forget about it.

As I'd mentioned in [your 
question about stock price returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143833/calculate-returns-on-a-daily-basis-in-r), a good R package for collecting and manipulating stock prices is `quantmod`.  Try:

```
library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "AAPL")
getSymbols(symbols, src = 'google')
closing.prices <- merge.xts(GOOG[,4], AMZN[,4], FB[,4], AAPL[,4])["2016-12-30/"]
```

Note that everything will be done using `xts` time series.  The time series `closing.prices` will be prices since the end of 2016, and can be converted to a series of returns using `ROC` from the `TTR` package:

```
library(TTR)
price.returns = ROC(closing.prices)
```

For our portfolio which is 25% equal-weighted at the start of every day, the portfolio returns will be the means:

```
rowMeans(price.returns)
```

The more realistic case where a portfolio was 25% equal-weighted at the start of the year, you might compute the overall returns of each stock, then compute the mean of the four:

```
mean(as.numeric(closing.prices["2017-09-12"]) / as.numeric(closing.prices["2016-12-30"]) - 1)
```

where `closing.prices["2017-09-12"]` is the closing price today, `closing.prices["2016-12-30"]` was the closing price at the start of the year.

Comment: Hi, Could you explain the command mean(as.numeric(closing.prices["2017-09-12"]) / as.numeric(closing.prices["2016-12-30"]) - 1) once again? I am unable to get the output. it shows me the error: Object: closing.prices not found.  Thanks.