# Calculate the differences between cells in the columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a STOXX investment universe that comes from [from here](https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt):

```
 head(df)

        Date   SX5P   SX5E  SXXP  SXXE  SXXF  SXXA   DK5F  DKXF
1 1986-12-31 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
2 1987-01-01 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
3 1987-01-02 770.89 891.78 82.57 97.80 97.43 69.37 647.62 65.81
4 1987-01-05 771.89 898.33 82.82 98.60 98.19 69.16 649.94 65.82
5 1987-01-06 775.92 902.32 83.28 99.19 98.83 69.50 652.49 66.06
6 1987-01-07 781.21 899.15 83.78 98.96 98.62 70.59 651.97 66.20
```

To understand the principles of allocation of actions. I have to **determine, *at the end of each month*, the allocation so that each share contributes the same risk to the total portfolio.**

Then I follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/python-data/assessing-the-riskiness-of-a-portfolio-with-python-6444c727c474) that makes you for Python.

But, on the one hand, I have problems calculating daily returns. In fact I have all the data thanks to:

```
url <- 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = ';', skip = 4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')
df$Date <- as.Date(sub('(.{2}).(.{2}).(.{4})', "\\3-\\2-\\1", df$Date))
```

And then I have to calculate them. I have seen that [there is a function, `Delt`](https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/Delt.html) that says to be able to do it between two columns. But I have to make the differences between each cell. I do not know how to do it:

```
new = df[2:9]
# How to calculate the returns ?
Delt(df.a_given_day,df.a_given_day_plus_1,k=0:2)  #... Delt do it 0,1 y 2 periods between two columns.
```

After, I could calculate the covariance with `cov_matrix_df <- cov(data.matrix(new, rownames.force = NA))` and continue my search to calculate the risk.

On the other hand I do not know how to modify it to determine, *at the end of each month* the risk to decide *at the end of each month*, the allocation.

#### my attempt:

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143833/calculate-returns-on-a-daily-basis-in-r) I tried from this answer:

```
dr_df = cbind(df[-1,1],apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1)))
```

Which returns:

```
> head(dr_df)
                  SX5P         SX5E         SXXP         SXXE         SXXF         SXXA
[1,] 6209  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,] 6210 -0.005303226 -0.010035301 -0.002295795 -0.007912355 -0.006424638  0.004488850
[3,] 6213  0.001297202  0.007344861  0.003027734  0.008179959  0.007800472 -0.003027245
[4,] 6214  0.005220951  0.004441575  0.005554214  0.005983773  0.006517975  0.004916136
[5,] 6215  0.006817713 -0.003513166  0.006003842 -0.002318782 -0.002124861  0.015683453
[6,] 6216 -0.004595435 -0.013101262 -0.003103366 -0.011014551 -0.009531535  0.005949851
              DK5F          DKXF
[1,]  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
[2,]  0.0036574404  0.0038133008
[3,]  0.0035823477  0.0001519526
[4,]  0.0039234391  0.0036463081
[5,] -0.0007969471  0.0021192855
[6,] -0.0098164026 -0.0087613293
```

Which seems quite good but I don't understand the code :/ And when I try to create the covariance matrix I have some issues:

```
> cov(dr_df[2:8])
Error in cov(dr_df[2:8]) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
> cov(dr_df)
             SX5P SX5E SXXP SXXE SXXF SXXA DK5F DKXF
     9886513   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SX5P      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SX5E      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXP      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXE      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXF      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXA      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DK5F      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DKXF      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

#### Soren's attempt

It seems that I have non-numeric argument to binary operator for `SX5P - SX5P1d` :

```
> library(lubridate)
Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    hour, mday, month, quarter, wday, week, yday, year

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> library(data.table)
> 
> 
> url <- 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
> df <- read.table(url, sep = ';', skip = 4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')
> df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)
> df$End_month_date <- ceiling_date(df$Date,unit="month") - days(1)
> 
> dt <- as.data.table(df)
> 
> #daily returns
> dt[, c("last_date",'SX5P1d','SX5E1d','SXXP1d','SXXE1d','SXXF1d','SXXA1d','DK5F1d','DKXF1d') := shift(.SD[,c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')], n=1, fill=NA, type=c("lag")),]
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'last_date' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
2: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SX5P1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
3: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SX5E1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
4: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SXXP1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
5: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SXXE1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
6: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SXXF1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
7: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'SXXA1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
8: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'DK5F1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
9: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("last_date", "SX5P1d", "SX5E1d",  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 7673 items of column 'DKXF1d' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
> dt[,`:=`(SX5P_r=SX5P-SX5P1d,
+          SX5E_r=SX5E-SX5E1d,
+          SXXP_r=SXXP-SXXP1d,
+          SXXE_r=SXXE-SXXE1d,
+          SXXF_r=SXXF-SXXF1d,
+          SXXA_r=SXXA-SXXA1d,
+          DK5F_r=DK5F-DK5F1d,
+          DKXF_r=DKXF-DKXF1d)]
Error in SX5P - SX5P1d : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> #monthly returns
> returns <- dt[,list(SX5P=sum(SX5P_r,na.rm=T),
+                     SX5E=sum(SX5E_r,na.rm=T),
+                     SXXP=sum(SXXP_r,na.rm=T),
+                     SXXE=sum(SXXE_r,na.rm=T),
+                     SXXF=sum(SXXF_r,na.rm=T),
+                     SXXA=sum(SXXA_r,na.rm=T),
+                     DK5F=sum(DK5F_r,na.rm=T),
+                     DKXF=sum(DKXF_r,na.rm=T)),by="End_month_date"]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(SX5P = sum(SX5P_r, na.rm = T), SX5E = sum(SX5E_r,  : 
  object 'SX5P_r' not found
```

Here is `dt` after `shift` operation that generated the warning messages :

```
> head(dt)
         Date   SX5P   SX5E  SXXP  SXXE  SXXF  SXXA   DK5F  DKXF End_month_date
1: 1986-12-31 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56     1986-12-31
2: 1987-01-01 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56     1987-01-31
3: 1987-01-02 770.89 891.78 82.57 97.80 97.43 69.37 647.62 65.81     1987-01-31
4: 1987-01-05 771.89 898.33 82.82 98.60 98.19 69.16 649.94 65.82     1987-01-31
5: 1987-01-06 775.92 902.32 83.28 99.19 98.83 69.50 652.49 66.06     1987-01-31
6: 1987-01-07 781.21 899.15 83.78 98.96 98.62 70.59 651.97 66.20     1987-01-31
   last_date SX5P1d SX5E1d SXXP1d SXXE1d SXXF1d SXXA1d DK5F1d DKXF1d
1:        NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2:      Date   Date   Date   Date   Date   Date   Date   Date   Date
3:      SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P   SX5P
4:      SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E   SX5E
5:      SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP   SXXP
6:      SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE   SXXE
```

Comment: Your precise question is a little unclear, but perhaps in lubridate package you can find floor_date or ceiling_date to get what you need in terms of end-of-month?  For example: library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(ymd("1987-01-06"),unit="month") - days(1)
> "1987-01-31"

Comment: I can also suggest you look into using a rolling join in the library(data.table), or possibly the data.table's shift() function to offset daily returns by one-day (or one-row) to calculate the daily difference.

Comment: @Soren Thank you ! I'm having a look. I modified a bit my question and added an attempt which seemed quite good but which I was unable to get the most of in the long run. I'm trying to create the same matrix but for monthly returns and which I can use in order to create a covariance matrix (for a risk analysis)

Comment: I suggested an solution using data.tables, which returns monthly returns in terms of sum of daily differences.

Comment: @Soren Yes ! I tried it and updated the post with the answer I got. It seems to take non binaries as argument. The warnings looked weird too : assigning not enough things to the columns.

Comment: you shouldn't be receiving these error messages on column assignments for daily returns as the output of shift() should be equal to the new column names set in c() before := ? I re-ran the suggested solution with a cleared environment and do not get these myself.  I'm not sure what might cause the difference off hand... Do you have latest version of data.table package installed?  Does running: dt[,shift(.SD[,c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')], n=1, fill=NA, type=c("lag"))] give 9x7673 expected dimension output?

Comment: Version seems unlikely, but worth checking. For reference, on my side: > packageVersion("data.table") =  ‘1.10.4.3’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data has some erratic values on dates 2016-03-25 and 2016-03-28.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, SX5P>0)            # drop erratic data points
percent_change <- function(x) (x - lag(x)) / lag(x) # function that calculates percentage change 
daily_return <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-Date), percent_change) %>%     # for each column excluding Date, apply percent_change function
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%                  # filter out NAs
  select(-Date) %>%                              # drop Date variable 
  as.matrix()                                    # convert to matrix                   

head(daily_return, 5)
#             SX5P         SX5E         SXXP         SXXE         SXXF         SXXA          DK5F         DKXF
#[1,]  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.0000000000 0.0000000000
#[2,] -0.005303226 -0.010035301 -0.002295795 -0.007912355 -0.006424638  0.004488850  0.0036574404 0.0038133008
#[3,]  0.001297202  0.007344861  0.003027734  0.008179959  0.007800472 -0.003027245  0.0035823477 0.0001519526
#[4,]  0.005220951  0.004441575  0.005554214  0.005983773  0.006517975  0.004916136  0.0039234391 0.0036463081
#[5,]  0.006817713 -0.003513166  0.006003842 -0.002318782 -0.002124861  0.015683453 -0.0007969471 0.0021192855

cov(daily_return)  
#             SX5P         SX5E         SXXP         SXXE         SXXF         SXXA         DK5F         DKXF
#SX5P 0.0001458898 0.0001531675 0.0001339905 0.0001400356 0.0001335696 0.0001283412 0.0001355236 0.0001410957
#SX5E 0.0001531675 0.0001781671 0.0001431415 0.0001622366 0.0001519764 0.0001252829 0.0001497803 0.0001561299
#SXXP 0.0001339905 0.0001431415 0.0001267415 0.0001328073 0.0001265858 0.0001210988 0.0001314346 0.0001359420
#SXXE 0.0001400356 0.0001622366 0.0001328073 0.0001502001 0.0001410354 0.0001165071 0.0001412857 0.0001471070
#SXXF 0.0001335696 0.0001519764 0.0001265858 0.0001410354 0.0001343114 0.0001130397 0.0001380515 0.0001432671
#SXXA 0.0001283412 0.0001252829 0.0001210988 0.0001165071 0.0001130397 0.0001257977 0.0001221743 0.0001254364
#DK5F 0.0001355236 0.0001497803 0.0001314346 0.0001412857 0.0001380515 0.0001221743 0.0001914781 0.0001946354
#DKXF 0.0001410957 0.0001561299 0.0001359420 0.0001471070 0.0001432671 0.0001254364 0.0001946354 0.0002103559
```

### monthly return

```
library(lubridate)
percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return <- df %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix()  
head(monthly_return, 5)

            SX5P         SX5E        SXXP         SXXE         SXXF       SXXA        DK5F        DKXF
[1,]  0.00000000  0.000000000 0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
[2,] -0.01089032 -0.046335561 0.005316578 -0.025867316 -0.025494595 0.04170287 -0.02977095 -0.01281269
[3,]  0.03167912 -0.009493186 0.032518367 -0.011141476 -0.011708861 0.07918740  0.05577361  0.04355828
[4,]  0.02633308  0.031731340 0.025284157  0.027359491  0.027197099 0.02322630  0.04121760  0.03157433
[5,]  0.02660200 -0.002816901 0.023347620 -0.003767437 -0.002362366 0.05061867  0.03758165  0.03917672

cov(monthly_return)
            SX5P        SX5E        SXXP        SXXE        SXXF        SXXA        DK5F        DKXF
SX5P 0.002068415 0.002243488 0.002011784 0.002160762 0.002076261 0.001867744 0.002282369 0.002381529
SX5E 0.002243488 0.002712719 0.002225923 0.002605715 0.002448324 0.001857319 0.002549326 0.002671546
SXXP 0.002011784 0.002225923 0.002025003 0.002182308 0.002095078 0.001873543 0.002321951 0.002407614
SXXE 0.002160762 0.002605715 0.002182308 0.002548197 0.002399266 0.001826243 0.002514475 0.002629281
SXXF 0.002076261 0.002448324 0.002095078 0.002399266 0.002291523 0.001797954 0.002458753 0.002558314
SXXA 0.001867744 0.001857319 0.001873543 0.001826243 0.001797954 0.001927949 0.002134767 0.002189677
DK5F 0.002282369 0.002549326 0.002321951 0.002514475 0.002458753 0.002134767 0.003414248 0.003523391
DKXF 0.002381529 0.002671546 0.002407614 0.002629281 0.002558314 0.002189677 0.003523391 0.003813587
```

## data.table version

```
library(data.table)
per_change <- function(x)x/shift(x) - 1
setDT(df)
df <- df[SX5P>0]
daily <- df[, lapply(.SD, per_change), .SDcols=-"Date"][-1, ]
daily
cov(daily)
monthly <- df[, lapply(.SD, percent_change2), by = .(gr=floor_date(Date, unit = "month")), .SDcols=-"Date"][-1, -"gr" ]
cov(monthly)
```

Comment: Thank you ! What is `%>%`? It creates some errors to me (I'm using RStudio)

Comment: `%>%` is a piping operator that is shipped with the package `dplyr`.

Comment: `data.table + dplyr code now lives in dtplyr.` I downloaded this one, then. Furthermore I have issues at creating `daily_return` : `Error: is.fun_list(calls) is not TRUE`. Last, I have to _determine the allocation such that each stock contributes the same risk to the total portfolio, at the end of each month_ Do you know how can I shift from daily analysis to monthly ?

Comment: @ThePassenger updated the answer. You might want to learn dplyr or data.table and figure out yourself.

Comment: I tried the functions on another file and when assigning `gr` it created an unexpected error : `object gr not found`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution shifts the values by one date (which is probably better than one literal date date to accommodate missing days, weekends, holidays, etc).  It finds the difference of 'today' and 'yesterday' as the return and sums the totals for the entire month, aggregating by last-day-of month.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)


url <- 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = ';', skip = 4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')
df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)
df$End_month_date <- ceiling_date(df$Date,unit="month") - days(1)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

#daily returns
dt[, c("last_date",'SX5P1d','SX5E1d','SXXP1d','SXXE1d','SXXF1d','SXXA1d','DK5F1d','DKXF1d') := shift(.SD[,c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')], n=1, fill=NA, type=c("lag")),]
dt[,`:=`(SX5P_r=SX5P-SX5P1d,
         SX5E_r=SX5E-SX5E1d,
         SXXP_r=SXXP-SXXP1d,
         SXXE_r=SXXE-SXXE1d,
         SXXF_r=SXXF-SXXF1d,
         SXXA_r=SXXA-SXXA1d,
         DK5F_r=DK5F-DK5F1d,
         DKXF_r=DKXF-DKXF1d)]
#monthly returns
returns <- dt[,list(SX5P=sum(SX5P_r,na.rm=T),
                    SX5E=sum(SX5E_r,na.rm=T),
                    SXXP=sum(SXXP_r,na.rm=T),
                    SXXE=sum(SXXE_r,na.rm=T),
                    SXXF=sum(SXXF_r,na.rm=T),
                    SXXA=sum(SXXA_r,na.rm=T),
                    DK5F=sum(DK5F_r,na.rm=T),
                    DKXF=sum(DKXF_r,na.rm=T)),by="End_month_date"]
```

Results:

```
> returns
     End_month_date   SX5P    SX5E   SXXP   SXXE   SXXF   SXXA    DK5F   DKXF
  1:     1986-12-31   0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00   0.00
  2:     1987-01-31  -8.44  -41.74   0.44  -2.55  -2.50   2.88  -19.21  -0.84
  3:     1987-02-28  21.55  -18.11   2.53  -1.95  -1.87   6.15   41.03   3.32
  4:     1987-03-31  24.13   28.47   2.67   2.80   2.62   2.53   31.40   2.53
  5:     1987-04-30  25.96   12.02   2.33   0.96   0.82   3.44   22.66   2.64
 ---                                                                         
355:     2016-06-30 -94.12 -198.74 -17.57 -20.95 -20.18 -13.80 -384.00 -22.60
356:     2016-07-31  64.29  126.02  12.01  15.55  16.22   8.23  219.13  18.83
357:     2016-08-31 -14.71   32.37   1.64   3.98   2.69  -0.67  -26.23  -4.42
358:     2016-09-30 -19.74  -20.89  -0.61  -0.45  -0.79  -0.76  -48.93  -0.71
359:     2016-10-31  27.89   27.26   3.18   2.42   3.14   3.83   96.24   5.45
```

Comment: `dt[,shift(.SD[,c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')], n=1, fill=NA, type=c("lag"))]` gives me back `[1] NA     "Date" "SX5P" "SX5E" "SXXP" "SXXE" "SXXF" "SXXA" "DK5F"` and my data.table version is 1.9.6

Comment: I get 9 auto-named columns V1, V2, V3...V9.  This is the key point, that the script is assigning 9 results to 9 names; and that's what's generating the error and note about recycling, that there's a mismatch.  Your output there is missing "DKXF" -- double check where you set names().  You can try setting the .SDcols to ensure only 9 cols are being passed in.  It's possible there is a version issue... "dt[,shift(.SD[,c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')], n=1, fill=NA, type=c("lag")),.SDcols=c("Date",'SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')]"

Comment: I thought I set the names as you were with : `names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')`. It seems to include `DXKF`. (by the way if you want to include preformated code use backquotes ` `code` `)

Comment: Ok, hopefully that'll be the fix that resolves.  Thanks also for the tip on the formatting (somehow didn't realize it was doable in comments).  Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure ;) The name setting seemed to be okay. I rather think it has something to do with the shift. I've updated the question with `dt` table after shifting.